How to mock and perform asserts in MessageBox
I'm making a desktop/on-premise application using C# .Net Windows Forms and I need to perform some tests on a class that interacts with the user through messages while carrying out some processes, and to cover the flow with unit tests I need to check if the messageBox was called and with what parameters. Can anyone help me how can I do it?
I tried to do this with the MessageBox class but I couldn't and I don't want to have a Windows Forms reference in my testing project.

You will have to wrap you message box in a injectable service.
public interface IDialogs
{
    bool ShowMessageBox(string message, string? title = null);
}

// Possible implementation.
class MyDialogs : IDialogs
{
    public bool ShowMessageBox(string message, string? title = null)
        => MessageBox.Show(message, title ?? "Default Caption") == DialogResult.OK;
}

// Mocked implementation
// (using C# 12 primary constructor, but works with normal constructor and field as well)
class MockedDialogs(bool expectedResult) : IDialogs
{
    public bool ShowMessageBox(string message, string? title = null)
        => expectedResult;
}


I was trying a few ways here and ended up finding a way to test it! I'll put it here so in case anyone has this difficulty, there will already be a way around it.
It's even a simple solution. Abstracting the implementation into another class and provide an interface for tests, here's an example:
public interface IMessageService
{
    DialogResult ShowMessage(string message, string title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon);
}

public class MessageBoxService : IMessageService
{
    public DialogResult ShowMessage(string message, string title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, icon);
    }
}

ps. you will still have to reference the Windows Forms DLL to use MessageBoxIcon, MessageBoxButtons and DialogResult.
If you want to remove the entire dependency, you will have to use other parameters and convert within the implementation.
